# Is APK published under alpha testing available for everyone in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a published apk in production say version 1.0. Now I added some more features in app and before publishing in production I want to publish it in Alpha testing. However, I want to ensure that this (alpha version) will not be available publicly and previous production version will remain available to everyone on play store. Will it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the alpha version will only be available for the Alpha testers. You can add Alpha testers using Google Groups and Google+ Communities.

Non-alpha testers will download the published app(version 1.0), until you move the Alpha version to production.

You might want to keep in mind that the alpha stage is only for APK's, and not for store listing etc. Updating screenshots will update them on all channels.

Comment: thanks. Will alpha testers be able to download production version from play store? Alpha testers are getting the alpha release whether to download through alpha testing link or from google play search. why is that?

Comment: Alpha testers will not be able to download the production version. They are able to opt-in and opt-out for alpha testing using the same link.
They basically sign up for the alpha channel, and the Play Store will handle all future updates. If you upload a new alpha version, all alpha testers will see the update in the Play Store within a few hours. It'll even automatically update if their update settings allow it. It works similar to the [Chrome release channels](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

Answer (score 2):

Your previous production version **will remain in production** and  available to everyone!
If you add a new alpha version, it will not influence this.
The new alpha version will be only available for a group of people (googlegroups). You can add or remove alpha testers with this group.